# Converting delphi statement to c#

Tags: c#, delphi

I have a Delphi statement that I need to convert to C#, but I am not sure how the pointer dereferencing works in this circumstance.

```pascal
var
  myarray : array[0..15] of WORD8;
  pBuf : PWORD32Buf;
begin
  ...
  pBuf := @myarray;
  Result := pBuf^[0] xor pBuf^[1] xor pBuf^[2] xor pBuf^[3];
end;
```

I understand that `pBuf` points to `myarray` and that `pBuf^[0]` should therefore be the 32 bit value represented by the first 4 bytes of the array. But I am not clear what 4 bytes would be represented by `pBuf^[1]`.

Would this be bytes 4 to 7 of `myarray`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can only guess at the answer, because we don't know what `PWORD32Buf` is. Presumably it is a pointer to an array of `DWORD`, where `DWORD` is an unsigned 32 bit integer. And we also need to guess what `WORD8` is, presumably an 8 byte type, probably unsigned.

In which case `pBuf^[0]` is bytes 0 to 3, `pBuf^[1]` is bytes 4 to 7, and so on. That would make sense because it would mean that all 16 bytes are included in the xor expression.

Comment: Thank you. I have made the same assumptions regarding PWORD32Buf and WORD8 as I do not have the type definitions for them. The key issue was the way the dereferencing worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [BitConverter.ToIn32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_BitConverter_ToInt32_System_Byte___System_Int32_) to acheive this:

```
byte[] myarray = new byte[16];

var result = BitConverter.ToInt32(myarray, 0) ^ 
             BitConverter.ToInt32(myarray, 4) ^
             BitConverter.ToInt32(myarray, 8) ^
             BitConverter.ToInt32(myarray, 12) ;
```

If you want to make an unsigned number then use [ToUInt32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.touint32?view=netframework-4.8) rather than `ToInt32`

Comment: Thanks. Your answer implicitly shows the same dereferencing solution.